# Set field data using data from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, html-table

I have a car rental system. A user can view a table of available cars and click a 'book' link. It directs them to the page `bookings/new`. What I want is the user id of the current user and the car ID of the car picked from the available cars table to automatically be entered into the new booking form.

Currently, the available cars table is displayed to users like this:

```
#cars#index

<%if logged_in_as_staff?%>
<h2>Available Cars</h2>

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<th>Car name</th>
<th>Manufacturer</th>
<th>Registration</th>
<th>Colour</th>
<th></th>

</tr>

<% @cars_available.each do |car| %>
 <tr>
   <td><%= car.car_name %></td>
   <td><%= car.manufacturer %></td>
   <td><%= car.registration %></td>
   <td><%= car.colour %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Book', new_booking_path %></td>


 </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>

<br />
<%= link_to 'Menu', main_menu_staff_path %>
```

Is there a way of transferring the data through the `link_to`, or do I have to def a method in the bookings or cars controller?

My booking form looks like this:

```
<%if logged_in_as_staff? %>
<%= form_for(@booking) do |f| %>
 <% if @booking.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">

    <ul>
      <% @booking.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :booking_no %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :booking_no%>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :car_id %><br />
  <%= f.number_field :car_id %>
</div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
  </div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :date %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :date %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link should be like that:

```
<%= link_to 'Book', new_booking_path(car_id: car.id) %>
```

And in your form

replace

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :car_id %><br />
  <%= f.number_field :car_id %>
</div>
```

with

```
<%= f.hidden_field, :car_id, value: params[:car_id] %>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i get an error with the hidden field. unexpected ':' after value. i also get it with the link after car_id. is ':' the correct syntax. im using rails 3.2.6 btw

Comment: i used :value => params[:car_id] and it worked, thanks for the help

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I used new hash syntax which requires ruby 1.9 > that was the problem.